# What does the phrase "can't work something" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have come across in the TV show *Friends*. It's in the 14th episode of the 5th season. The context is Phoebe pretends that she wants to have sex with Chandler which she doesn't, so that she can make Chandler admit that he is in a relationship with Monika. Chandler also pretends that he want to have sex with Phoebe, which he also doesn't. They kind of have a competition where they try to make each other back down. Here the transcript of the scene and the [video](https://youtu.be/xBes0eZYuUw). It's at 2 minutes and 12 seconds.

> Joey: I like that! (To Phoebe) Oh, okay! Show him your bra! He's afraid of bras! **Can't work 'em**! (He swiftly rips open the front of Phoebe's dress revealing her bra.)

Does Joey mean that Chandler can't take off bras?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a short version of "Can't work them out" which Joey prefers to say it like that. He means "Chandler cannot figure out how to undo bras" or "it's very hard for him to undo bras".